# jquery .live not called

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

let's say on an HTML document I have a bunch of links like so:

```
<a href="#path" class="the_link_1">Click here 1</a>
<a href="#path" class="the_link_2">Click here 2</a>
<a href="#path" class="the_link_3">Click here 3</a>
<a href="#path" class="the_link_4">Click here 4</a>
etc...
```

I have jquery code like this:

```
$("a[class^=the_link_]").each(function(){

    $(this).live("click", function(){

        alert($(this).html());

    });

});
```

Why is this working when I use `$(this).click(function(){ ... });` but it does not work when I use `$(this).live("click", function(){ ... });` ?

Thank you

Comment: You should understand how `.live()` works before using it. Then once you understand it, you should stop using it.

Answer (score 6):

`.live` is weird, and only works with selectors.  By that I mean `$('div').live` works and `$(div).live` doesn't.

Also, you don't need `.each` when applying a click handler to multiple elements. `$("a[class^='the_link_']").click` works as expected.

Your code should be:

```
$("a[class^='the_link_']").live("click", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

UPDATE: As of jQuery 1.7, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
$(document).on('click', "a[class^='the_link_']", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

NOTE: If all the `<a>` tags are in one container, you can replace `$(document)` with that container (as long is it's always in the DOM).

EDIT: Do you really need to use `.live` here?  It's used to bind the event to elements even if they are added to the DOM later.  If you never add more `<a>` tags via JavaScript, then just do this:

```
$("a[class^='the_link_']").click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: And, it's deprecated after 1.7 in favor of `on`

Comment: I am NOT using jQuery 1.7, I am on jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: @user765368: Then don't use `.on` :-P

Comment: @user765368 That's OK. Rocket has the answer for both before and after 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the apostrophes around `the_link_`. And it's too much complicated at all.

Just keep it simple:

```
$("a[class^='the_link_']").live("click", function(){
        alert($(this).html());
});​
```

`live` is deprecated, btw, since jQuery 1.7. Use `on` instead.

```
$(document).on("click", "a[class^='the_link_']", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sfsdx/

[**.on() – jQuery API**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Smile! :)**

Comment: `$("a[class^='the_link_']").on("click"` is not the same as `$("a[class^='the_link_']").live("click"`.

Comment: `$("a[class^='the_link_']").on("click"` binds to the elements currently in the DOM.  `$(document).on('click', "a[class^='the_link_']"` is how to bind to elements added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using? If you're using 1.7.x - the .live() method is deprecated. See the [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

That said, you can try the .on method:

```
$(this).on('click', function(){ .... }
```

Comment: I am NOT using jQuery 1.7, I am on jQuery 1.4.2